# Understanding how to declare functions in typescript interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning Typescript and I get stuck defining an Interface:

Javascript code is this:

```
const client: Client = new Resource({ token: 'xyz' });

client.events.create({
  id: userId,
  event: eventName,
  created: formatDate(date)
}, doSomething(cb));
```

What I did is:

```
interface Client {
  events: EventsClient;
}

interface EventsClient {
  create(args: CreateEventsClient, cb: Function): void;
}

interface CreateEventsClient {
  id: string;
  event: string;
  created: Date;
}
```

I tried a few different approaches but I always end up with the following errors:

1. Argument of type `'{ id: string; event: string; created: Date; }'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'CreateEventsClient'`.
2. Expected 4 arguments, but got 2.

How should I create this interface?

Comment: where did `metadata: any` come from? don't you need to add it to `CreateEventsClient`?

Comment: Just removed many properties to let it be readable. It would be better to focus on the interface...

Comment: Please include the defintions of `doSomething` and `fromDate` (I am interested in the signature not the body). I tried your code and it works fine, at least with the definitions I added that were missing.  The only thing is that  `cb` would be better as a more specific `Function` type not a  generic `Function`

Comment: I managed to let it work using the code posted in the question, I was just naming properties wrong. Thanks for your help.